# New User ID not working in custom function with user_register hook

Tags: users, hooks, wpdb, user-registration

I'm adding data to a table whenever a new user registers on the site.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_follow_admin', 10, 1 );

function auto_follow_admin() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_um_followers', array( 
    'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
    'user_id1' => 1, 
    'user_id2' => $user_id 
        ) 
    );
}
```

Everything works fine apart from the the new $user_id which isn't being passed to the query.

The stored data after it's run looks like this :

```
time : 2015-08-27 14:08:32
user_id1 : 1
user_id2 :
```

Is **global $wpdb;** resetting the user_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to give your function a parameter:

```
function auto_follow_admin( $user_id ) {

    // Now you can use $user_id, which is passed to the function from the hook caller

}
```

Comment: Ahh I feel stupid now.. How did I miss that! Thanks man ;)